# Debug org-mode link to PDF displayed with PDF-Tools

Tags: org-mode, debug

Emacs 24.5 on openSuse Tumbleweed. *.org file with a link to a pdf:

```
[[.\somefile.pdf::2][myfile p 2]]
```

I'm using the PDF Tools to display a PDF in Emacs. What I expect is that page 2 of the PDF will be shown. But it always opens on page 1.

I have no idea, what could be wrong. I [asked](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2016-04/msg00506.html) on the orgmode-mailinglist, [as well](https://github.com/markus1189/org-pdfview/issues/10) as the maintainer of org-pdfview.el -- without any success.

Unfortunately I'm lacking of lisp skills. How could I debug e.g. org-pdfview.el and find out, why it does not provide a pagenumber to PDF-Tools?

I open org-pdfview.el, M-x eval-buffer, point the cursor inside a function and "instrument" it: C-u S-M-C-x. But how can I change to an org-mode buffer containing a link like given above? If I just change the buffer and open a link `C-c C-o`, I never get any reaction inside the buffer of org-pdfview.el.

Well, I ran out of ideas.

---

Edit:

In my .emacs there are these commands:

```
(eval-after-load 'org '(require 'org-pdfview))
(delete '("\\.pdf\\'" . default) org-file-apps)
(add-to-list 'org-file-apps '("\\.pdf\\'" . org-pdfview-open))
(add-to-list 'org-file-apps '("\\.pdf::\\([[:digit:]]+\\)\\'" . org-pdfview-open))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you sure you are using the right link? It looks like you need: pdfview:./somefile.pdf::2 to me, at least based on https://github.com/markus1189/org-pdfview/blob/master/org-pdfview.el#L39

Comment: you might also see if this interactive command works: pdf-view-goto-page

On MacOSX, it doesn't seem to do anything for me. This is the command used to open the page you want, so it might be the problem.

Comment: You are right, placing a `pdfview:` at the beginning of the link => pdf is opened on the specified page. So there is something wrong with the rest of org-pdfview.el : It is not meant to require the `pdfview` inside the link and this would also break its usage within abbreviated links of the kind `[[shortcut:./foo.pdf][foo]]`. Could you have a look into the file, whether you notice something? (By the way, the system blocks spending the bonus for 8 more hours, however, thank you!) `pdf-view-goto-page` works as expected.